# How to fill angled element with text without cutting it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to make text like this ( blue 'circle' ). I am opened for any HTML/css(3) solution. If its not possible to make it with pure html/css could you please give me some js solution if there is one..

[image: Angled element - Blue circle]

Comment: Nope, not with CSS at present. There is the shapes module which would help but as of now it has very poor browser support. There was a similar question earlier on SO where OP ended up splitting each line into an element and then progressively assigning width or something like that.

Comment: I thought so. I have received design from designers without any background in web design so I've ended with this one. I have tried it to make it like that ( splitting into different lines ) but as you know its useless on responsive websites. Thank you anyway. Cheers.

Comment: Here, have a look at this thread and it might give you some ideas - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876883/align-text-on-slanted-shape/27878676#27878676